# How do I apply conditional formatting on the values of a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-formatting

I have a JavaScript array with multiple values that I am trying to apply conditional formatting to.

[Example of what I am trying to produce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT0Th.png)

```
let teamData = [
    { teamName: 'AFC Bournemouth', GW34FIX: "TOT(H)", GW34: 0.6, GW35FIX: "LEI(H)", GW35: 0.74, GW36FIX: "MCI(A)", GW36: 0.80, GW37FIX: "SOU(H)", GW37: 0.75, GW38FIX: "EVE(A)", GW38: 0.99, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Arsenal', GW34FIX: "LEI(H)", GW34: 1.20, GW35FIX: "TOT(A)", GW35: 1.11, GW36FIX: "LIV(H)", GW36: 0.98, GW37FIX: "AVL(A)", GW37: 1.44, GW38FIX: "WAT(H)", GW38: "Update", AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Aston Villa', GW34FIX: "MUN(H)", GW34: 0.51, GW35FIX: "CRY(H)", GW35: 1.00, GW36FIX: "EVE(A)", GW36: 0.86, GW37FIX: "ARS(H)", GW37: 0.75, GW38FIX: "WHU(A)", GW38: "Update", AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Brighton & Hove Albion', GW34FIX: "LIV(H)", GW34: 0.94, GW35FIX: "MCI(H)", GW35: 0.85, GW36FIX: "SOU(A)", GW36: 0.71, GW37FIX: "NEW(H)", GW37: 1.09, GW38FIX: "BUR(A)", AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Burnley', GW34FIX: "WHU(A)", GW34: 1.26, GW35FIX: "LIV(A)", GW35: 1.01, GW36FIX: "WOL(H)", GW36: 1.22, GW37FIX: "NOR(A)", GW37: 2.37, GW38FIX: "BHA(H)", GW38: 1.46, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Chelsea', GW34FIX: "CRY(A)", GW34: 1.39, GW35FIX: "SHU(A)", GW35: 1.14, GW36FIX: "NOR(H)", GW36: 2.14, GW37FIX: "LIV(A)", GW37: 0.97, GW38FIX: "WOL(H)", GW38: 0.97, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Crystal Palace', GW34FIX: "CHE(H)", GW34: 0.72, GW35FIX: "AVL(A)", GW35: 1.00, GW36FIX: "MUN(H)", GW36: 0.42, GW37FIX: "WOL(A)", GW37: 0.56, GW38FIX: "TOT(H)", GW38: 0.49, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Everton', GW34FIX: "SOU(H)", GW34: 0.96, GW35FIX: "WOL(A)", GW35: 1.08, GW36FIX: "AVL(H)", GW36: 1.16, GW37FIX: "SHU(A)", GW37: 0.75, GW38FIX: "BOU(H)", GW38: 1.01, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Leicester City', GW34FIX: "ARS(A)", GW34: 0.83, GW35FIX: "BOU(A)", GW35: 1.35, GW36FIX: "SHU(H)", GW36: 0.72, GW37FIX: "TOT(A)", GW37: 0.88, GW38FIX: "MUN(H)", GW38: 0.81, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Liverpool', GW34FIX: "BHA(A)", GW34: 1.06, GW35FIX: "BUR(H)", GW35: 0.99, GW36FIX: "ARS(A)", GW36: 1.03, GW37FIX: "CHE(H)", GW37: 1.03, GW38FIX: "NEW(A)", GW38: 1.34, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Manchester City', GW34FIX: "NEW(H)", GW34: 0.83, GW35FIX: "BHA(A)", GW35: 1.17, GW36FIX: "BOU(H)", GW36: 1.25, GW37FIX: "WAT(A)", GW37: "Update", GW38FIX: "NOR(H)", GW38: 2.51, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Manchester United', GW34FIX: "AVL(A)", GW34: 1.96, GW35FIX: "SOU(H)", GW35: 1.10, GW36FIX: "CRY(A)", GW36: 2.36, GW37FIX: "WAT(A)", GW37: "Update", GW38FIX: "LEI(A)", GW38: 1.24, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Newcastle United', GW34FIX: "MCI(A)", GW34: 1.20, GW35FIX: "WAT(A)", GW35: 1.34, GW36FIX: "TOT(H)", GW36: 0.70, GW37FIX: "BHA(A)", GW37: 0.92, GW38FIX: "LIV(H)", GW38: 0.75, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Norwich City', GW34FIX: "WAT(A)", GW34: 0.84, GW35FIX: "WHU(H)", GW35: 0.54, GW36FIX: "CHE(A)", GW36: 0.47, GW37FIX: "BUR(H)", GW37: 0.42, GW38FIX: "MCI(A)", GW38: 0.40, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Sheffield United', GW34FIX: "WOL(H)", GW34: 0.90, GW35FIX: "CHE(H)", GW35: 0.87, GW36FIX: "LEI(A)", GW36: 1.39, GW37FIX: "EVE(H)", GW37: 1.34, GW38FIX: "SOU(A)", GW38: 1.02, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Southampton', GW34FIX: "EVE(A)", GW34: 1.04, GW35FIX: "MUN(A)", GW35: 0.91, GW36FIX: "BHA(H)", GW36: 1.41, GW37FIX: "BOU(A)", GW37: 1.33, GW38FIX: "SHU(H)", GW38: 0.98, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Tottenham Hotspur', GW34FIX: "BOU(A)", GW34: 1.67, GW35FIX: "ARS(H)", GW35: 0.9, GW36FIX: "NEW(A)", GW36: 1.42, GW37FIX: "LEI(H)", GW37: 1.14, GW38FIX: "CRY(A)", GW38: 2.04, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Watford', GW34FIX: "NOR(H)", GW34: 1.19, GW35FIX: "NEW(H)", GW35: 0.75, GW36FIX: "WHU(A)", GW36: 0.86, GW37FIX: "MCI(H)", GW37: "Update", GW38FIX: "ARS(A)", GW38: "Update", AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'West Ham United', GW34FIX: "BUR(H)", GW34: 0.79, GW35FIX: "NOR(A)", GW35: 1.85, GW36FIX: "WAT(H)", GW36: 1.16, GW37FIX: "MUN(A)", GW37: "Update", GW38FIX: "AVL(H)", GW38: "Update", AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 },
    { teamName: 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', GW34FIX: "SHU(A)", GW34: 1.11, GW35FIX: "EVE(H)", GW35: 0.93, GW36FIX: "BUR(A)", GW36: 0.82, GW37FIX: "CRY(H)", GW37: 1.79, GW38FIX: "CHE(A)", GW38: 1.03, AVG: "", FDR: 0.69 }
];
```

I am trying to show the text of GW3XFIX and apply a background color based on the value of GW3X.
The number of GW3X is a given rating based on an algorithm. I want to color grade the field based on the size of its number. If under 0.7, then dark red, if between 0.7 and 0.9 then red, if between 0.9 and 1.1 then grey, if between 1.1 and 1.3 then green, if above 1.3 then dark green.

This is how I am loading the HTML table.

```
function loadTableData(teamData) {
    const tableBody = document.getElementById('teamData');
    let dataHtml = '';

    for(let team of teamData) {
        dataHtml += `<tr><td>${team.teamName}</td><td>${team.GW34FIX}</td><td>${team.GW35FIX}</td><td>${team.GW36FIX}</td><td>${team.GW37FIX}</td><td>${team.GW38FIX}</td><td>${team.AVG}</td></tr>`;
   }
    
    tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I have tried multiple methods but without success.

Comment: Can you add a class or a style property to your html in your template literal depending on the condition ?

Comment: _"I have tried multiple methods but without success."_ - You've missed to add at least one of them. Split up the string concatenation and add some `if ... else ...` or use the ternary operator in the template.

Comment: Is `teamData` an array or an object?  
I suspect object.  
Remove the un-closed array opener `[`...
Or is it an example of one of the objects in an array?  
If so, add an array closer `]`...

Comment: @iAmOren I only added one line of the array since it's rather large, I forgot to add the closer.

Comment: Got it - re-read and saw you are referring to an array.  Sorry about that... :)

Comment: Can you show us the 4 objects that are in your image example?
Also, I'm confused about the 4 colors: 3 - ok: win, lose, draw - what's the 4th color?
Or, what do the colors mean?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, last time I did I got flamed so I decided not to.

Comment: This is what confuses me: "I want to show half of the array" - do you mean "half of each object in the array?  
As in taking pairs like `GW34FIX: "TOT(H)", GW34: 0.6, `, show `GW34FIX`'s value with bacground color depending on `GW34`'s value - "TOT(H)" with "0.6"ish bgcolor?  
What are the ranges for colors?  is the value between 0 and 1?  How many colors?

Comment: @iAmOren The number is a rating given based on an algorithm. I want to color grade the field based on the size of its number. If under 0.7, then dark red, if between 0.7 and 0.9 then red, if between 0.9 and 1.1 then grey, if between 1.1 and 1.3 then green, if above 1.3 then dark green. I will edit the post to add this clarification.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function color(value) {
  return value<0.7?"darkred":
         value<0.9?"red":
         value<1.1?"grey":
         value<1.3?"green":
         "darkgreen";
}

function loadTableData(teamData) {
  var columns=Object.keys(teamData[0]).filter(key=>key.includes("FIX")).map(key=>key.slice(0,key.length-3));
  var tableHTML="";
  tableHTML+="<table>";
  tableHTML+="<tr>";
  tableHTML+="<th>Team</th>";
  for(var i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
    tableHTML+="<th>"+columns[i]+"</th>";
  }
  tableHTML+="</tr>";
  for(var t=0; t<teamData.length; t++) {
    tableHTML+="<tr>";
    tableHTML+="<td>"+teamData[t].teamName+"</td>";
    for(var c=0; c<columns.length; c++) {
      tableHTML+="<td bgcolor='"+color(teamData[t][columns[c]])+"'>"+teamData[t][columns[c]+"FIX"]+"</td>";
    }
    tableHTML+="</tr>";
  }
  tableHTML+="</table>";
  document.getElementById('teamData').innerHTML=tableHTML;
}
```

Assuming all objects have the same properties, it's safe to use any of them to extract pairs of data, so I've used `teamData[0]` to get an array of key-pairs, like so: `Object.keys(teamData[0])`.
With that, I've `filter`ed out the keys that have "FIX" in their name: `filter(key=>key.includes("FIX"))`.
Then, I've mapped those keys, just without the "FIX" part: `map(key=>key.slice(0,key.length-3))`.
We are left with an array of key-pair-name: `columns`.
The first loop (and lines before and after) creates the header for the table.
Then, we create a row for each team using index `t`, starting with `teamName`, and then looping through key-pairs, using key for `bgcolor` and key+"FIX" for value, using a `color` function that returns a color based on the key's value.
Note: you can change the colors to better fit your needs.  "silver" is lighter than "gray", for example.
And, finally, we place the whole `tableHTML` in the `teamData`'s element's `innerHTML`.

This is what I got from it:
[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you! I will try to work through it myself to understand. You've done more than enough, been trying to figure this out for a couple of weeks. Thanks again :)

Comment: You are very welcome!
Meanwhile, while you were writing your comment, I've explained how this works in an edit to my answer... :)

Comment: You can use element creation like in the other answer, I didn't use your string literals, I'm sure there are more elegant ways to solve this, etc... :)

Comment: Creating the `columns` array "extraction" is the main thing (in my opinion) to totally investigate and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```js
function loadTableData(teamData) {
    const tableBody = document.getELementById("teamData");

    teamData.forEach((team) => {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        Object.keys(team).forEach((key) => {
            if (key == "teamName") {
                let el = document.createElement("td");
                el.innerText = team[key];
                row.prepend(el);
            } else if (key.match(/^GW3\dFIX$/) != null) {
                let el = document.createElement("td");
                el.innerText = team[key];
                el.style.background = team[key.replace("FIX", "")];
                row.append(el);
            }
        });

        tableBody.append(row):
    });
}
```

Here we utilise `Array.forEach` which calls a function on each element in the array (in this case, each team). Instead of your method of appending strings, we're going to create nodes from within the JS (using `document.createElement`), which makes things a little easier for us.

Next, we use `Object.keys()` which returns the keys of an object as an array, again allowing us to iterate over it using the wonderful `Array.forEach`. We test the key to see if it is `teamName`, which won't be guaranteed to be first, which is why the element we create for it is prepended to the row, so it will be at the start.

Otherwise, if it matches the regex of a team name (`/^GW3\dFIX$/`), a new cell can be created, filled with the text content and colored using the same key, except with `FIX` removed.

All this is appended to the row, which is finally appended to the table!